# Graphviz graphs with Sphinx Python documentation generator errors

Tags: python, python-sphinx, graphviz

I'm trying to generate graph in my python documentation using graphviz in Sphinx despite putting it in my list of extensions and using the this :

```
digraph foo {
      "bar" -> "baz";
   }
```

for graph example i still get an error of **Unknown directive type "graphviz".** and nothing is printed in my html. despite looking everywhere I didn't find a solution for this... can someone please help ? thanks

Comment: Please show us your list of extensions in conf.py.

Comment: extensions = [ 'sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx_autodoc_typehints','sphinx.ext.graphviz'] @mzjn

Comment: That looks good. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: To use the graphviz package, I had to add the directory to my environment `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'C:\Program Files (x86)\graphviz-2.38\release\bin'`

Comment: is there's another way ? because that doesnt work for me ... @Bugbeeb